# IE <= 8 removes <form> tag when received from AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm making an AJAX POST call to get some HTML. I take that HTML and inject it into the DOM. Everything works fine and dandy in every browser except for IE <= 8. It seems like IE is parsing the incoming HTML since when I log it to console/alert it, tags are in capitals.

The line it's removing:

```
<form class="uniForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profile/editprofile/" method="post">
```

Very bizarre because the end  tag is there but the start tag isn't. The call is a standard jQuery POST ($.post()).

**UPDATE:**

Ended up giving up and putting it into an embedded textarea and reinjecting into the DOM:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<textarea class="ieHackTextArea">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<![endif]-->
```

... somewhere else ...

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseFloat($.browser.version) < 9) {
    ui.panel.innerHTML = $(".ieHackTextArea").val(); // jQuery injection doesn't work
}
```

Comment: restrict access to IE7 browsers :p

Comment: The only IE this works in is IE 9! IE 7 doesn't work either.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the exact same problem today and managed to fix it by inserting an empty `<pre></pre>` right before the `<form>`, which somehow stops `IE8` (haven't tested in other versions) from removing the `<form>`.

Comment: Been fighting with this all day, had a previous case where wrapping it in a div worked but this time it didnt, putting an empty pre before it worked a treat this time, thank you very much!

Comment: I can't believe this actually worked. I'm in shock. IE9

Answer (score 1):

You can try to wrap all the form into a `<div>` to see if that works better.

I experienced the same issue with an `<input>` object and that was my solution to make sure it will work fine in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is fast and simple, just remove last slash from the action="" attribute (just in URL) of form tag.

Example:

**WRONG (IE)**

```
<form action="http://mywebsite.com/something/">
</form>
```

**CORRECT**

```
<form action="http://mywebsite.com/something">
</form>
```

Only remove the slash in the end of form action="".

Answer (score 0):

use navigator.userAgent inside your javascript handler to identify the browser and apply suiatble logic. It is straightfoward compare to "CSS hack".
You can reference here http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/

The userAgent of IE will most likely carry the String MSIE (Miscrosoft internextExplorer perhaps :D)

Basically:

```js
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 7.0') > -1){
   /* Do watever suitable for IE7 here */ 
}else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 8.0') >-1){
   /* Do watever suitable for IE8 here */ 
}else{
  /* The rest... */
}
```