# jquery dialog with file upload using ajaxSubmit not posting after failing validation (IE caching issue?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-dialog

This only happens in IE. Chrome and Firefox work fine. I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 and jQuery.

I have a jQuery dialog with a form that has a file upload, so I'm using ajaxSubmit to submit the form to the server. I am not using any client-side validation, but I AM using server-side validation on my model.

I am running the code in debug mode in Visual Studio with a breakpoint on the POST handler for this controller action. I pull up the dialog and fill out the form in a way that I know is invalid. When I click Save, I first get the alert('save'), then I get alert('beforeSubmit'), then my ajaxSubmit runs and hits the breakpoint on the "server". Validation fails and returns the new form with my red validation messages visible. Somewhere in there I get alert('success') and alert('complete'). All is well. Then I fix the data on the form to be valid and click Save again.

This time I get alert('save') and that's it. Nothing else. No other alerts, no breakpoint, nothing. Fiddler doesn't even register a POST. Again, this only happens in IE. Chrome and Firefox work fine.

Please help.

```
function save() {
    alert('save');
    $('#household-member-form').ajaxSubmit({
        url: '/Wizard/HouseholdMember',
        target: '#dialog-household-income',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        },
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            alert('beforeSubmit');
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert('complete');
        },
        async: false
    });
}
```

EDIT: I also have this in my controller action:

HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

EDIT 2: Also, any feedback on how I could re-word this question to get a better response would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried the same with simple .ajax ?  Also, try returning false, to prevent browser default behavior.

Comment: @viperguynaz I can't use a simple $.ajax because I have a file upload on the form that $.ajax won't work for. That's why I'm using the Form plugin. I'm going to try removing the file upload now and see if a regular $.ajax call will work. Maybe that will narrow it down. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: SOLUTION: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970116/ie-8-removes-form-tag-when-received-from-ajax

The <pre></pre> option worked.